# Php скрипт отправляет на почту пустые письма

Tags: php, form

1. Скрипт иногда отправляет на почту пустые письма хотя поля формы required
2. В error_log появляются ошибки:

- PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /public_html/sendmail.php on line 19
- PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /public_html/sendmail.php on line 2

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mess = $_POST['mess'];

$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$mess = htmlspecialchars($mess);

$name = urldecode($name);
$email = urldecode($email);
$mess = urldecode($mess);

$name = trim($name);
$email = trim($email);
$mess = trim($mess);

# SEND -------------------------------
mail("pochta@yandex.ru", "Заявка с сайта MySite", "Имя: " . $name . " -||- " . "E-mail: " . $email , "$mess \r\n");
header("Location:https://mysite.ru");
?>
```

В чем проблема? Из-за чего на почту некоторые письма приходят пустыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас тело сообщения передаётся в параметр `additional_headers`, о чём нам сообщает первая ошибка

Как вы вызываете:

```
mail(
    "pochta@yandex.ru", // string $to
    "Заявка с сайта MySite", // string $subject
    "Имя: " . $name . " -||- " . "E-mail: " . $email , // string $message
    "$mess \r\n" // mixed $additional_headers
);
```

Как, вероятно, хотели:

```
mail(
    "pochta@yandex.ru", // string $to
    "Заявка с сайта MySite", // string $subject
    "Имя: " . $name . " -||- " . "E-mail: " . $email . "$mess \r\n" // string $message
);
```

[mail() | PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

Comment: Спасибо!! удалил error_log, внес изменения. тестирую.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

атрибут required поддерживают не все браузеры http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/required

также требуется делать валидацию на уровне php

2. > PHP Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /public_html/sendmail.php on line 19

4-ый параметр в вызове "$mess \r\n". additional_headers - Строка или массив, которые будут вставлены в конец отправляемых заголовков письма. Там не допускаются переводы строк

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: name in /public_html/sendmail.php on line 2

проверять параметр  if(isset($_POST['name']) ) { }

Comment: понял. это if (!empty())?

Comment: да. но лучше if(isset($_POST['name']) && (trim($_POST['name']) != '') ) { } + валидацию поля email на почтовый адрес сделать

Comment: ок. спасибо! а нет ли мыслей по поводу Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /public_html/sendmail.php on line 19?

Comment: 4-ый параметр в вызове "$mess \r\n". additional_headers - Строка или массив, которые будут вставлены в конец отправляемых заголовков письма. Там не допускаются переводы строк